# How to cache data for external API calls on Firebase or any custom server backend?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, architecture, database-connection, api-design

Im developing a React app which has a dashboard and other fields which display data from a 3rd Party API. I also have mobile apps(React Native and iOS) which also need to display the SAME data.
Since the 3rd party API has limits on the calls, if I have 1000 users, and I query the 3rd party API from the 1000 clients(client side invocation), I will reach that limit very quickly. My intention is to make API calls on the firebase database and then update the database every 30 minutes. So even if I have 1000 or 100 users, they will be hitting the firebase server for fetching data which in turn would be holding the cached data(A JSON object). 
Is there a way I can do this using Firebase? Or heroku? Which is the preferred way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own API with Firebase Functions and make that API do the requests to the 3rd party API and cache the results for 'x' time or write them to your Firebase Database using the Admin SDK.

Then your users will be able to fetch that data directly from your database without ever touching the 3rd party API.

Here you have a [videotutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&t=231s) from Firebase on how to create a Node.js app (hosting and functions). Functions section of the video is what you are looking for.

Hope it helps! :)